# Is there a way to treat a committed file like a staged file when I checkout branches?

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm writing a performance test for code that I've already committed to see what speed improvements I've made.  To do this, I created a branch of the code before my performance fix.

I have my test class staged which is convenient because I can checkout my branch and the test will be brought over to it.  But after I commit, I'll lose this functionality.  After I commit this test, is there a way to tell Git to treat the committed file like it's staged so it gets brought over when I change branches?

I'm using the Git-Svn bridge.

Answer (score 2):

You can always checkout the file you need from another branch, it's as simple as

```
git checkout another_branch relative_path_to_your_test_file.php
```

Comment: Probably the most practical solution.

Comment: If this test file is isolated to a commit, can I use the commit id instead of the relative path?

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what this does?

Comment: Instead of branch name -- yes, but you should have the second parameter, otherwise it will change the working tree, which is not exactly what you want if I'm getting it right.

Comment: @tieTYT It takes the file(s) from relative path (second parameter), from the specified branch/commit (first parameter), copies it over the working tree and stages.

Comment: @bredikhin is there a way to say, "all files from this commit", or would I have to specify all the relative paths of all the files in that commit?

Comment: @tieTYT You should be able to do `git checkout commit_or_branch .`, which means all the changes staring from the project root.

Comment: No, I have not tried this method.  That `relative_path_to_your_test_file.php` seems inconvenient.  I like the cherry-pick idea that @PaulHicks gave better, actually.

Answer (score 1):

Cherrypicking can also help.  You can [git cherry-pick](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) the change after switching branch, and use the `-n` option to avoid creating a new commit, so that it stays in the staging area.  It's easy to script cherry picking a single commit.

Another workflow that might help is [interactive staging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging).

Comment: Cherry picking sounds like a bad idea when the remote repo is SVN (like in my case).  "Given one or more existing commits, apply the change each one introduces, **recording a new commit for each**."

Comment: Hence the "-n": don't introduce a new commit.